# Julia Read CSV From Line

Tags: file, csv, julia

How do I read a text file that contains a delimited part, like in a CSV, from a specific line (that is, where the delimited part begins)? The file looks structurally like this:

```
[header]
1 2 3
4 5 6
[...]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I already found this solution:

```
A=readdlm("filename", ' ', skipstart=X)
```

Comment: Please mark your solution as the answer so this does not show up as unanswered. Thanks!